# can't insert the same data into 2 tables at the same time in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I need your help to fix my problem..
first I have 2 tables in mysql dbase.. here are the structures :

```
doctor1:
--------                         
no_que autoincrement pk,
doctor_name,
id_patient,
date,
time

status_que:
----------
id_patient,
doctor_name,
no_que fk,
date,
time
```

I want to insert data into doctor1 and the data will be the same at status_que..

```
$idp=$_POST['id_patient'];
$dt=$_POST['date'];
$tm=$_POST['time'];
$dn=$_POST['doctor_name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO doctor1 (doctor_name, id_patient, date, time) 
            values ('$dn', '$idp', '$dt', '$tm')"; 

$result = @mysql_query($query) or die("REPORT Failed to save data.");

$last_insert_no_que = mysql_insert_id();

@query2 = "INSERT INTO status_queue (id_patient, doctor_name, no_que, date, time) 
            values ('$idp', '$dn', '$last_insert_no_que', '$dt', '$tm')"; 


$result = @mysql_query($query2) or die("REPORT Failed to save data.");
```

but that code doesn't work

Comment: remove `@` operator and see if there are any errors... Also if i were you id use `PDO` and use a transaction here.

Comment: I'd probably remove the first line from your code... as it contains your credentials and all.

Comment: Even when this is edited out, it'd be still visible in the revision history until/if a moderator decides to remove that entry from the history. I'm flagging it for attention for your security, but I still recommend you to change your pass in the live server asap if that's the actual address, user and pass.

Comment: my fault .. thank's for your advice...I'll change my pass quickly :)

Comment: doctor_name field is not seen in your table structure..?

Comment: Change this part `or die("REPORT Failed to save data.")` to `or die(mysql_error())` and paste the content of the output here.

Answer (score 0):

it works ! I only have to delete "@" operator.. :) ~ thx you

so here is my code :

```
$idp=$_POST['id_patient'];
$dt=$_POST['date'];
$tm=$_POST['time'];
$dn=$_POST['doctor_name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO doctor1 (doctor_name, id_patient, date, time) 
            values ('$dn', '$idp', '$dt', '$tm')"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$last_insert_no_que = mysql_insert_id();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO status_queue (id_patient, doctor_name, no_que, date, time) 
            values ('$idp', '$dn', '$last_insert_no_que', '$dt', '$tm')"; 


$result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

>